# Update and Create New Records in the Same Table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-5, entity-relationship

How can I apply changes to the first record in a table and add one or more additional records to the same table? I am getting the following exception:

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager.
>   The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key

See sample code below.

```
var Student = db.Student.Where(d => d.StudentID == studentID);
                                        int count = 0;    
                                        if(Student != null)
                                            {
                                                foreach(var student in Student)
                                                {
                                                    if (student.Id == id)
                                                    {
                                                        foreach (var assign in assignment)
                                                        {
                                                            if (assign != null && count == 0)
                                                            {
                                                               //How can I save the changes that is made to the first record here
                                                                assign.AssignmentId = student.AssignmentID;
                                                                db.Assignment.ApplyCurrentValues(assign);
                                                            }

                                                            if (assign != null && count > 0)
                                                            {
                                                                //How can I add new records here
                                                                assign.AssignmentId = student.AssignmentID;
                                                                db.Assignment.AddObject(assign);
                                                            }
                                                            count++;
                                                        }
                                                    }


                                                }
                                            }
```

Comment: Not sure where, but you probably have to add `.Attach()` somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling save after this line i.e.

```
db.Assignment.ApplyCurrentValues(assign);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Then for your new entries:

```
var assignment = new Assignement() { AssignmentId = student.AssignmentID };
db.Assignments.Add(model);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: There is already a single template assignment record in the Assignment table at the beginning. It's missing the assignmentID which is a nullable foreign key. If a single assignment is returned, it's no problem. I simply updated the assignment with the assginmentID. However, if two or more assignments are returned, I have to updated the first template record with the correct assignmentID then add the rest of the assignment.

@hutchonoid, Thanks...I got the same exception. Attaching it did not help either.